# Property assignment expected react jsx

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to check if my variable `(item.label)` contains the string 'ToDate'.

However, i am getting the error `Property assignment expected` on this line
`({item.label} === 'ToDate') ? (`

```
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  {
                    isFilterSubmitted
                      ? filters.map((item, i) => (
                        {
                          ({item.label} === 'ToDate') ? (
                        <ChipComponent
                          label={`${item.label}: ${item.name}`}
                          key={item}
                          handleDelete={() => this.handleDelete(item.label, i)}
                        />
                          ) : null
                         }
                      ))
                      : ''
                  }
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Your arrow function brackets seem off, what you currently have would try and return an object containing a JSX element (With no property name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying what you currently have makes the issue clearer:

```
filters.map((item, i) => ({ boolean ? <ChipComponent /> : null }))
```

The outer `()` mean that this is trying to return an object `{<ChipComponent />}` without a property name, hence the property assignment error.

If you remove the inner `{}` it just will return either the JSX element or null:

```
filters.map((item, i) => ( boolean ? <ChipComponent /> : null ))
```

You are also directly checking equality, rather than partial matching, you can use `includes()` to achieve that.

Complete example:

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
{ isFilterSubmitted
    ? filters.map((item, i) => (
        item.label.includes('ToDate') 
            ? <ChipComponent
                label={`${item.label}: ${item.name}`}
                key={item}
                handleDelete={() => this.handleDelete(item.label, i)}
            />
            : null
        ))
    : ''
}
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the equality in any case

whatever value this expression produces `{item.label}` gets appended and show in browser.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-swanson-bzrqt?file=/src/App.js)

You should write logic in the `{}` not outside of this.

If you are checking if a string contains another string then you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

> Remember `includes` is case-sensitive search

```
{ item.label.includes("ToDate") }
```

```js
const str = "LargeStringSearchFrom";

console.log(str.includes("Search"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` as you are checking wether string has `ToDate` or not.

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
      {
        isFilterSubmitted
          ? filters.map((item, i) => (
            {
              (item.label.indexOf('ToDate')) ? (
            <ChipComponent
              label={`${item.label}: ${item.name}`}
              key={item}
              handleDelete={() => this.handleDelete(item.label, i)}
            />
              ) : null
              }
          ))
          : ''
      }
</Grid>
```

refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to know more about.